# Postgis SQL for nearest neighbors

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to calculate the nearest neighbors. For that, I need to pass a parameter to limit the maximum distance from the neighbors. For example, which are the nearest neighbors within a radius of 1000 meters?

I did the following :

I created my table with the data:

```
id | name | latitude | longitude
```

After that, I executed the following query :

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ( 'public' , ' green ', ' geom ' , 4326 , ' POINT' , 2 );

UPDATE season
SET geom = ST_Transform(ST_PointFromText ('POINT (' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')', 4269), 4326);
```

First question, Is the SRID of Brazil 4326? What would be 4269 ?

Second question, by doing the following SQL

```
SELECT id, name
FROM season
WHERE ST_DWithin (
                 geom ,
                 ST_GeomFromText ('POINT(-49.2653819 -25.4244287 )', 4326),
                 1000
                 );
```

This returns nothing. From what I understand, this SQL would further point the radius of the maximum distance, right?

It appears if you put 1000 results for 100000000, all my entries appear .

So, I wonder what is wrong here?

Comment: Please share sample data & output that is required.

Answer (score 7):

First, If you are using latitude, longitude, you need to use 4326.

```
UPDATE season SET geom = ST_PointFromText ('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')' , 4326 ) ;
```

Then you create an index on the geom field

```
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometryfield] );
```

Then you get the kNN neightbors:

```
SELECT *,ST_Distance(geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(newLon newLat)'::geometry) 
FROM yourDbTable
ORDER BY
yourDbTable.geom <->'SRID=4326;POINT(newLon newLat)'::geometry
LIMIT 10;
```

This query will take advantage of kNN functionality of the gist index (http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html).

Still the distance returned will be in degrees, not meters (projection 4326 uses degrees).

To fix this:

```
SELECT *,ST_Distance(geography(geom),ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(newLon newLat)') 
FROM yourDbTable
ORDER BY
yourDbTable.geom <->'SRID=4326;POINT(newLon newLat)'::geometry
LIMIT 10;
```

When you calculate the ST_distance use the geography type. There distance is always in meters:

http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html

All this functionality will probably need a recent Postgis version (2.0+). I am not sure though.

Check this for reference https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91765/improve-speed-of-postgis-nearest-neighbor-query/

Comment: He is trying to avoid lat/lon, that was the point with the original post, that ST_DWithin doesn't work very well with a distance of 1000 and lat/lon. I though of mentioning the <-> operator, but didn't want to confuse matters. It is actually a Postgres not a Postgis operator -- you can use it with text search too -- see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#K-Nearest-Neighbor_Indexing

Comment: The suggestion to use the geography type is a good one, though ideally there would be a projected Brazilian system he could use.

Comment: @JohnBarça. If he has lat-lon, using an additional projection might be more confusing. So, he may use geometry (for knn functionality) and geography for actual distance. Still, for meters I would probably use UTM (although Brazil may exceeds one UTM zone). That is why overall, geography might be a better solution, to avoid projection issues.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I tend to avoid geography where possible, because underneath a lot of the functionality is done via conversion to geometry first and I tend to think of it as most useful when you are dealing with the date line or the poles, which naturally cause issues with projected systems. However, if the OP just wants to take distances and has coordinates in lat/lon, your geography solution may well be the best option.

Comment: Thanks for the help, did it this way and it worked out just right: 


`SELECT *, ST_Distance (geography :: geom, 'SRID = 4326; POINT (-49.264791 -25.427251)' :: geography) the dist_m 
FROM season 
ORDER BY 
Geomagnetic <-> 'SRID = 4326; POINT (-49.264791 -25.427251)' :: geometry 
LIMIT 10; '

Comment: Then you may accept the answer, if you found it useful.

Comment: Yes, I tried to answer your original question, but I think Alexandros's answer is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Hello, is results of this query is exactly? For my data some points ordered wrong(order by distance give right results, but slowly) =(

Comment: @FallDi Order by distance in degrees<> Order by distance in meters. Which of the two you want?

Comment: @Alexandros I wanna order by distance using index. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find information in Postgis on spatial reference systems look in the table spatial_ref_sys. Based on that and to answer you first question,

```
select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=4629
```

returns the following:

```
4269 | EPSG      |      4269 | GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983"
,SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],AUTHORITY["
EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01
745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]] | +proj=long
lat +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +no_defs
```

This indicates that it is a North American Datum, and not Brasil, using the GRS80 ellipse, which is not the same as the WGS84 one used by 4326, which is the standard used by GPS. This information is what is used by the Proj4 projections library, which is included as part of a Postgis build on Postgres.

I searched for Brasil in spatial_ref_sys,

```
select * from spatial_ref_sys where auth_name ilike '%Bras%';
```

and this returned no results.

I did find a reference to 29101 on the web, which uses a South American datum, with a Brazilian Polyconic projection and units in metres.

To convert you original example to this, you could use:

```
select ST_Astext(ST_Transform(ST_SetSrid(ST_Makepoint(-49.265, -25.424),4326), 29101));
```

which returns:

POINT(5476247.04359163 7178517.77380949)

and would allow you to use ST_Distance or ST_DWithin in meters. I only put the ST_AsText so you can see the output, you obviously wouldn't actually use that in an update using ST_Transform.

Note the use of ST_Makepoint instead of concatenating coordinates -- the same thing, but easier to read, imho.

To answer your second question, because you are effectively working in 4326, lat/lon, which ranges from -180 to 180 and -90 to 90, if you used 1000 as the distance in ST_DWithin, you will get every record returned, because the 1000 is not meters, but degrees, so you would have to use something like the system above.

If you want to take distance in lat/lon, have a look at the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) which will work fine for short distances.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for my ignorance, I have never worked with GIS, so sorry if I'm talking nonsense, but from what I understand, if I use SRID 4326 will not be able to do the calculations for the values ​​of my lat and long are not compatible right? You said you did not find an SRID to Brazil, so I would not have another option? As to the parameter ST_DWithin meters but not degrees, there is some function that makes picking meters? Thank you and again sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: Don't apologize, projections are hard to understand, and there doesn't seem to be much coherent information on Brasil. It looks like there is work underway to establish a new spatial infrastructure for Brasil. I have updated my original answer with some more information. If this has helped, please consider accepting the answer. If not, ask more.

Comment: Thanks again, one last thing, you said that ST_DWithin calculated in degrees, not meters, I would like to pass the parameter in meters? There is a parse? Thank you.

Comment: No, I said that the reason you were getting so many results is because you were using ST_DWithin with 1000 as the distance and in degrees. If you do the transform I suggested above, it should work with meters.