# PostGIS: How to find N closest sets of points to a given set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, gis, geospatial, postgis

I am using PostGIS/Rails and have sets of points with geolocations.

```
class DataSet < ActiveRecord::Base  # these are the sets containing the points
  has_many :raw_data
  # attributes: id , name
end

class RawData < ActiveRecord::Base  # these are the data points
  belongs_to :data_set
  # attributes: id, location which is "Point(lon,lat)"
end
```

For a given set of points I need to find the N closest sets and their distance;

*or alternatively:*
For a given max distance and set of points I need to find the N closest sets.

What is the best way to do this with PostGIS?

My versions are PostgreSQL 9.3.4 with PostGIS 2.1.2

Comment: I believe I can answer this, but could you clarify what you mean by a a set of points -- how are these points defined in the context of the question?

Comment: see comments in the code

Comment: OK, further clarification, in your comments to Alexandros you say find the nearest points in two sets whereas in the original question you say find the N closest sets to a point. Sorry for all the questions, but there are various ways of doing these things in Postgis, but with varying performance.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgerSQL 9.3.4 with PostGIS 2.1.2

Comment: I'm dealing with 'sets of points', e.g. multiple DB records containing points, each having a set_id, indicating set-membership.

There are different ways of formulating this query.

I quess this query would also work: 
"find N closest points where set_id is different from my reference point." => unique set-ids

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer on how to find the N-closest neighbours in PostGIS are given here:

[Postgis SQL for nearest neighbors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854105/postgis-sql-for-nearest-neighbors/)

To summarize the answer there:

You need to create a geometry object for your points. If you are using latitude, longitude, you need to use 4326.

```
UPDATE season SET geom = ST_PointFromText ('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')' , 4326 ) ;
```

Then you create an index on the geom field

```
CREATE INDEX [indexname] ON [tablename] USING GIST ( [geometryfield] );
```

Then you get the kNN neightbors:

```
SELECT *,ST_Distance(geom,'SRID=4326;POINT(newLon newLat)'::geometry) 
FROM yourDbTable
ORDER BY
yourDbTable.geom <->'SRID=4326;POINT(newLon newLat)'::geometry
LIMIT 10;
```

Where newLon newLat are the query points coordinates.

This query will take advantage of kNN functionality of the gist index (http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/knn.html).

Still the distance returned will be in degrees, not meters (projection 4326 uses degrees).

To fix this:

```
SELECT *,ST_Distance(geography(geom),ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(newLon newLat)') 
FROM yourDbTable
ORDER BY
yourDbTable.geom <->'SRID=4326;POINT(newLon newLat)'::geometry
LIMIT 10;
```

When you calculate the ST_distance use the geography type. There the distance is always in meters:

http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/geography.html

All this functionality will probably need a recent Postgis version (2.0+). I am not sure though.

Check this for reference https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91765/improve-speed-of-postgis-nearest-neighbor-query/

EDIT. This covers the necessary steps for one point. For set of points:

```
SELECT n1.*,n2.*, ST_Distance(n1.geom,n2.geom) 
FROM yourDbTable n1, yourDbTable n2
WHERE n1.setId=1 AND n1.setId=2 //your condition here for the separate sets
AND n1.id<>n2.id // in case the same object belong to 2 sets
ORDER BY n1.geom <->n2.geom
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have the geometry objects already in my PostGIS DB.
The SQL queries you listed are comparing points, not sets of points - I was trying to see if there is a query which basically can find the nearest points in two sets